# need a circuit that can switch motor direction by photo or timer input

Tags: motor, ac

I have a reversible 115 volt ac motor that has its own internal limit switches to cut the power. It has 4 wires to the motor green-ground and red-hot ,black-hot, and white-neutral. If I have the red and white connected to power it turns one way and the black and white connected it turns the other way. I would like to know what sort of circuit I can use to switch power from the red wire to black wire and back depending on light levels or timer input. ie red wire powered by increasing light and black powered by decreasing light. It is for a door to be opened in the morning and closed in the evening.
Thanks

Comment: oops got my motors mixed up--will edit question

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear, but is sounds like you want a double pole double throw switch.

Comment: yes I need DPDT action but I would like it to be controlled by an LDR for both directions. It does not need to shut off because the motor has internal limit switches to adjust number of rotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a DPDT relay and photo-transistor made for turning on an outdoor light. You can buy them at any hardware store... DPDT relay for 110vAC at radioshack.

Comment: use the normal side of relay connection for daylight and the other for dark. With the photo transistor triggering the relay.

Answer (score 0):

might be easier for you to use DC motor and a DPDT switch or H bridge driver from   12V to DC motor. With Direction and Enable inputs and triggered by your choice.